# How do I get the opacity of an element using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

If I have:

```
#em {
  opacity:0.5;
}
```

How do I get `#em`'s opacity using `javascript`? :D

I've got troubles with the following (it returns nothing):

```
return document.getElementById("em").style.opacity;
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Setting a CSS value in a stylesheet is not the same as setting it through the `style` property. You need to look at the [`getComputedStyle`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.getComputedStyle) method to obtain this (and also `currentStyle` for older IE).

Comment: For IE you need a workaround since it doesn't have getComputedStyle, example: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/dhtmlcascade4.shtml

Answer (score 23):

```
var em = document.getElementById("em");
var  temp = window.getComputedStyle(em).getPropertyValue("opacity");
```

Now, the variable *temp* will have the value of opacity of "em".

Answer (score 3):

```
document.getElementById("em").style.opacity;
```

it will work fine if you use inline style .eg.

```
<div id="em" style="width: 50px; height: 50px; opacity: 0.5;">
```

Comment: its opacity* btw