# Opacity on div using css not defined, but with js it is defined

Tags: javascript, css, opacity

I have a div with an id with `opacity:0.75;` and this shows the div on the screen with 0.75 opacity. When i want change the opacity with js it doesn't work - I used an alert to see the style.opacity value but the alert comes up blank. If i instead have ...`style.opacity = "0.75";` in the js code it does work (onscreen the object looks 75% opaque like it should and the alert comes up with 0.75). Why is this?

`label.style.opacity = parseFloat(label.style.opacity, 10) - 0.1; alert(label.style.opacity);`

and css

```
#label {
width:100px;
text-align:center;
height:50px;
font-size:normal;
position:absolute;
color:white;
z-index:100;
font-family:Helvetica-Light;
}
```

Comment: `label.style.opacity = parseFloat(label.style.opacity, 10) - 0.1; alert(label.style.opacity);` and css `#label {
width:100px;
text-align:center;
height:50px;
font-size:normal;
position:absolute;
color:white;
z-index:100;
font-family:Helvetica-Light;
}`

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `getComputedStyle` on the element to get values set by CSS. See this answer: [How do I get the opacity of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365296/how-do-i-get-the-opacity-of-an-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
label.style.opacity = (parseFloat(label.style.opacity) || 1) - 0.1;
```

If the element does not have a set value for the `opacity` property, `.style.opacity` will return an empty string. My code default the value to `1`.

Comment: what does the or sign do? oh return 1 when opacity is not set. but that doesn't fix the problem because i set the opacity in css and it returns an empty string

Comment: @DylanThepiguy Unless you have a good reason not to, use a library for CSS operations. E.g. with jQuery, you can retrieve the value with `$(label).css('opacity')`