# console not working and function starts working late

Tags: javascript, html, css, console

It's like javascript doesn't respect the style definitions in the css and only respects the changes made in css by javascript itself:

```
<body onload="fader()">

    <img id="ssio" src="../images/slideshow/1.jpg" alt="slideshow" style="width:100%;height:80%;" />
    <img id="ssie" src="../images/slideshow/2.jpg" alt="slideshow" style="width:100%;height:80%;" />

<!--css work-->

<style>

img#ssio{
    transition:opacity 1s;
    position:absolute;
    opacity:1;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}
img#ssie{
    transition:opacity 1s;
    opacity:0;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
}

</style>

<!--js work-->

<script>

function fader() {
    console.log(document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity, document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity, ",", ssion, ssien)
    document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity = document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity;
    document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity = 1 - document.getElementById("ssio").style.opacity;
    setTimeout(fader, 4000);
}

</script>
</body>
```

Why doesn't it work as expected?
Why do console and js treat the defined opacity in css as null?
How can I fix it?

Comment: <style></style> in you're body ? <style> always in <head>

Comment: in my real code its in external stylesheet, so is my js.

Comment: @jay can you explain more?

Comment: It's just a guess at why you might getting a null value. Try adding `.getPropertyValue()` to the end of your selector.

Comment: You have multiple `setTimeout` functions on body `onload` which increases the page load time by 20 seconds.

Comment: @jay why so summarized!?when i add it at the end of the selectors right after.opacity, it errors that is not a function!why don't you add an answer and write down your suggestion properly?:)

Comment: @lucky so what?anyways, i deleted them.

Comment: I'm at work and was briefly reading through. I meant like this to get the value of your opactiy: `.getElementById( "ssio" ).getPropertyValue( "opacity" );`

Comment: its still insists thats not a function!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are some problems in your function:

First, you forgot to define what are variables ssion and ssien which is why there is no log written in console.

The second problem is that JavaScript doesn't look at the properties in the stylesheet(however it looks at the properties in the in-line style). So since initially when the document loads, you haven't defined opacity in the in-line style, thus `document.getElementById("ssie").style.opacity` has no value which means after the first run of your function you'll end up setting opacity of ssie to 1.

You can read the answer of the topic [How do I get the opacity of an element using Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365296/how-do-i-get-the-opacity-of-an-element-using-javascript) for further information about how you might fix this.

However, in my opinion the correct way of doing this is actually using `display` or `visibility` CSS properties. you might want to look them up.

Comment: well, sry for those two vars, i defined them in my actual code but forgot to copy the definitions here as well, but yeah, the problem was with that inline definition.and well, idk whats the advantage of using display and visibility, regarding this code is a part of a slideshow, but anyways, i'm now busy reprograming the whole thing with jQuery due to cross-browser incompatibilities.thanks for your time:)