# How do I set opacity of an element using JS?

Tags: javascript, firefox, opacity

I know how to set it in a style sheet. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365296/how-do-i-get-the-opacity-of-an-element-using-javascript) explains how to get it using JS...

I tried this to set it:

```
window.getComputedStyle( myEl ).setPropertyValue( 'opacity', 0.7 );
```

and got

> setPropertyValue is not a function.

Obviously I can use JQuery `css( ... )`... in the `min.js` file I found there were no fewer than 10 matches for `opacity`. I didn't have a clue about what was going on.

This is Firefox, by the way.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By modifying the [`style` property.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/style)

```
myEl.style.opacity = 0.7;
```

Comment: Thanks very much.  This is quite mysterious to me: when I tried to **get** the opacity by going `myEl.style.opacity` it didn't even print "undefined" or "null"... just, seemingly, nothing at all!

Comment: @mikerodent If you see nothing at all then it's an empty string ;)

Comment: I presumed it was ... it'd be strange indeed if there were a "void" or "absence of anything" in JS somehow apart from null, NaN and undefined!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the live example for opacity change:

```js
var target = document.getElementById('target');
var currentOpacity = window.getComputedStyle(target).opacity;

function decreaseOpacity() {
  if (currentOpacity > 0) {
    target.style.opacity = currentOpacity - 0.1;
    currentOpacity -= 0.1;
  }
}

function increaseOpacity() {
  if (currentOpacity < 1) {
    target.style.opacity = currentOpacity - 0.1;
    currentOpacity += 0.1;
  }
}
```

```css
#target {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: violet;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<button onclick="decreaseOpacity()">Decrease opacity</button>
<button onclick="increaseOpacity()">Increase opacity</button>
```