# Javascript How to rotate an image that's in a series of unique id's?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a series of images with unique id's. In javascript we can rotate them by id by using JavaScript however, I haven't found a way to allow the user to rotate them individually when I have unique id's attached to them. The unique id's are assigned by some PHP code:

```
<div id="'.$i.'" class="view_class"><div id="container">
    <img src="'.$rowdel.'" class="view_image_class" id="image"/>
</div></div>
<button class="sho" class="rotate_left" id="rotate_left">Rotate Left</button>
```

and my javascript:

```
 var angle = 0, img = document.getElementById('container');
document.getElementById('rotate_left').onclick = function() {
  angle = (angle + 90) % 360;
  img.className = "rotate" + angle;
}
```

and my css:

```
#container {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 800px;
    overflow: hidden;
    position:absolute;
}
#container.rotate90,
#container.rotate270 {
    width: auto;
    max-height: 800px;
    position:absolute;

}
#image {
    transform-origin: top left;
    /* IE 10+, Firefox, etc. */
    -webkit-transform-origin: top left;
    /* Chrome */
    -ms-transform-origin: top left;
    /* IE 9 */
}
#container.rotate90 #image {
    transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(90deg) translateY(-100%);
}
#container.rotate180 #image {
    transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg) translate(-100%, -100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(180deg) translateX(-100%, -100%);
}
#container.rotate270 #image {
    transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);
    -ms-transform: rotate(270deg) translateX(-100%);

}
```

I would like the user to be able to rotate the images individually so that image 12 (for example) is rotated and the other images aren't. Then I would like javascript to keep that rotation in memory so that when viewing image 12 again it is displayed rotated.

So far it is only rotating image #1. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why did this get a vote down?

Comment: your CSS looks like you're applying the rule to a single element by ID. `#container.` probably needs to be `view_image_class.` and then you need to ensure you don't lose that classname in `img.className = "rotate" + angle;`

Comment: I'm experimenting with that atm but it still only rotates the 1st image

Comment: if each image has an ID, you'd change `document.getElementById('container')` based on that ID

Comment: I did that with `document.getElementById('i')` but it's still only rotating the first image.

Comment: `document.getElementById('rotate_left')` I think you keep getting trapped on using ID's for everything, you can use class names as your selectors and fetch additional data via `data-` attributes. I'm also not seeing your rotate left buttons in the code samples. Only one element can have a specific ID.

Comment: I added the rotate left button in the code samples. How to fetch additoinal data with the `data-` tag for this example?

Comment: Checkout my answer, I've got a simplified working solution.

Comment: You've tagged your question with `php`, `ajax`, and `javascript`, when actually yours is a question about `CSS`.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my rendition of what you're trying to achieve

Each image has a unique ID, the buttons are grouped by class `rotate_left` and `rotate_right` in which the functionality is applied. It makes use of `data-image-id` and `data-angle` and the storage containers for the image target and the rotation value.

`<span id="img1-angle"></span>` is added just for your own visual reference.

**Rotate Individual Images** https://jsfiddle.net/zdap6Lfr/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        img.rotate90 {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        img.rotate180 {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        img.rotate270 {
            transform: rotate(270deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);

        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" id="img1"/>
            <button class="rotate_left" data-image-id="img1">Rotate left</button>
            <button class="rotate_right" data-image-id="img1">Rotate Right</button>
            <span id="img1-angle"></span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" id="img2"/>
            <button class="rotate_left" data-image-id="img2">Rotate left</button>
            <button class="rotate_right" data-image-id="img2">Rotate Right</button>
            <span id="img2-angle"></span>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" id="img3"/>
            <button class="rotate_left" data-image-id="img3">Rotate left</button>
            <button class="rotate_right" data-image-id="img3">Rotate Right</button>
            <span id="img3-angle"></span>
        </div>
        <script>
            var left_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("rotate_left");
            for (var i = 0; i < left_buttons.length; i++) {
              left_buttons[i].onclick = function(){
                var image = document.getElementById( this.getAttribute("data-image-id") );
                var angle = image.getAttribute("data-angle") ? parseInt( image.getAttribute("data-angle") ) : 0;
                angle = ( angle + 90 ) % 360;
                image.setAttribute('data-angle',angle);
                image.className = "rotate" + angle;
                document.getElementById( this.getAttribute("data-image-id")+ "-angle").innerText = angle;
              }
            };
            var right_buttons = document.getElementsByClassName("rotate_right");
            for (var i = 0; i < right_buttons.length; i++) {
              right_buttons[i].onclick = function(){
                var image = document.getElementById( this.getAttribute("data-image-id") );
                var angle = image.getAttribute("data-angle") ? parseInt( image.getAttribute("data-angle") ) : 0;
                angle = ( angle + 270 ) % 360;
                image.setAttribute('data-angle',angle);
                image.className = "rotate" + angle;
                document.getElementById( this.getAttribute("data-image-id")+ "-angle").innerText = angle;
              }
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Rotate All (Image Class Level)** https://jsfiddle.net/fxbgzdLy/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        img.rotate90 {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        img.rotate180 {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        img.rotate270 {
            transform: rotate(270deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);

        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" class="rotate_image"/>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" class="rotate_image"/>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <div>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" class="rotate_image"/>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button id="rotate_left" data-image-id="img1">Rotate left</button>
        <button id="rotate_right" data-image-id="img1">Rotate Right</button>
        <span id="rotate_angle"></span>
        <script>
            var RotationAngle = 0;
            document.getElementById("rotate_left").onclick = function(){
                RotationAngle = ( RotationAngle + 90 ) % 360;
                var images = document.getElementsByClassName('rotate_image');
                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
                {
                  images[i].className = "rotate_image rotate" + RotationAngle;
                }
                document.getElementById( "rotate_angle").innerText = RotationAngle;
            };
            document.getElementById("rotate_right").onclick = function(){
                RotationAngle = ( RotationAngle + 270 ) % 360;
                var images = document.getElementsByClassName('rotate_image');
                for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++)
                {
                    images[i].className = "rotate_image rotate" + RotationAngle;
                }
                document.getElementById( "rotate_angle").innerText = RotationAngle;
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

**Rotate All (Container ID Level)** https://jsfiddle.net/mzh3wwom/

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
        #rotate_container.rotate90 img.rotate_image {
            transform: rotate(90deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(90deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(90deg);
        }
        #rotate_container.rotate180 img.rotate_image {
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(180deg);
        }
        #rotate_container.rotate270 img.rotate_image {
            transform: rotate(270deg);
            -webkit-transform: rotate(270deg);
            -ms-transform: rotate(270deg);

        }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div id="rotate_container" data-angle="0">
            <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" class="rotate_image"/>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" class="rotate_image"/>
            </div>
            <hr>
            <div>
                <img src="https://i.imgur.com/gdyZUEUb.jpg" class="rotate_image"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <hr>
        <button id="rotate_left">Rotate left</button>
        <button id="rotate_right">Rotate right</button>
        <span id="rotate_angle"></span>
        <script>
          document.getElementById("rotate_left").onclick = function(){
            var container = document.getElementById("rotate_container");
            var angle = container.getAttribute("data-angle") ? parseInt( container.getAttribute("data-angle") ) : 0;
            angle = ( angle + 90 ) % 360;
            container.setAttribute('data-angle',angle);
            container.className = "rotate" + angle;
            document.getElementById("rotate_angle").innerText = angle;
          };
          document.getElementById("rotate_right").onclick = function(){
            var container = document.getElementById("rotate_container");
            var angle = container.getAttribute("data-angle") ? parseInt( container.getAttribute("data-angle") ) : 0;
            angle = ( angle + 270 ) % 360;
            container.setAttribute('data-angle',angle);
            container.className = "rotate" + angle;
            document.getElementById("rotate_angle").innerText = angle;
          };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm trying to get the same `rotate` buttons to work with each of the images though, see; the viewer is displaying the images, and the viewer has `rotate_left` and `rotate_right` buttons at the bottom. Each image is then hidden with `opacity 0` and the image being displayed is set to `opacity 1`. The buttons are on the bottom and the same 2 buttons are used for all the images. So I can't use that code but I was thinking, if we could tie in your code so that it uses only 2 buttons for every image, perhaps using javascript to recognise that it has to rotate only images set to `opacity 1`.

Comment: Ah my mistake @ax.falcon, I've added two additional options, one is similar to your container level rotation. `rotate_image` is rotated based on the class on `#rotate_container` :)

Comment: Oh, sorry lol. I meant that the 2 buttons rotate the image with `opacity =1` only. But I will use your code definitely. I suppose I'd better ask a new question asking "how to test for opacity = 1" in javascript. Unless you want to add some code. You seem apt in javascript so can this be achieved?

Comment: Yeah you should be able to get the opacity style from the element programmatically. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11365296/how-do-i-get-the-opacity-of-an-element-using-javascript also please accept my answer if it is what you seek :)